# How to pass a parameter from a partial layout to a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a `form` partial within a shared partial layout `form_layout`

```
# views/layouts/shared/_form_layout.html.haml
= form_with(model: record, remote: true) do |form|
  .fields
    = yield
/// other stuff
```

```
# views/articles/_form.html.haml
# ?? want to access the form builder here
```

```
# views/articles/new.html.haml
= render partial: 'form', layout: 'layouts/shared/form_layout', locals: { record: Article.new }
```

How can I access the `FormBuilder` object inside the partial template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this-

```
= render layout: "layouts/shared/form_layout", locals: { record: Article.new} do
  # block contents..
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Right now I am using this:
`= render layout: 'layouts/shared/form', locals: { record: @article } do |form|`
`= render 'form', form: form`
But is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @ranjan_purbey Hi, feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.